# Multiple checkout locations from Perforce with CruiseControl [.Net]

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, perforce

I'm employing a production-test server, that is, a test server in the production environment, which is only accessible from my company's network. This is for doing smoke tests and regression tests (for example making sure that our 3rd party web services are accessible), before we actually deploy the project to production (the project is a web site).

We use a Perforce Source Control Server and CruiseControl.Net, and I'd like to configure the CruiseControl to check out our production code to two different file system locations (on our build server) so it can build it twice with different build configurations, i.e. one build configuration for production, one for production-test. Then I'm gonna robocopy the production-test build to the production-test server.

How do I specify multiple checkout directories for "production-test" and "production", without having to create two different branches for it?

Answer (score 2):

Create two separate projects. Use [Configuration Preprocessor](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Configuration+Preprocessor) to extract all common parts into a template and include it twice, changing only the project name, working/artifacts directories and the configuration. That's the simplest and most bulletproof solution.